# How to import a third-party library in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on my first Laravel project, and so far everything worked fine but now I need to use in my controller a PHP extension, this one: https://github.com/cyjoelchen/php-sweph.

I installed this extension successfully on my development machine, I can see that it was enabled when running `phpinfo()`, and I can use its functions when running a PHP script on the command line. So it is available, and it works. But I cannot use it in my Laravel controller, no matter what I try, it is 'not found'. I suspect I should register with the Laravel app somehow, but how? And how do I refer to it in my controller then?

Comment: You did run `phpinfo()` in your Laravel application? If not make sure your Laravel application is using the same PHP version. Or add the `extension=sweph.so` to the correct `php.ini` file.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas! I did the following: run `phpinfo()` in my controller and displayed the output in the view. I made sure that it's the same PHP and the same php.ini. However, I couldn't find any mention of `sweph` in it. So I restarted the machine, and voila — sweph appeared in the output of `phpinfo()` in the controller! However, I still have no idea how to use it in the code. I tried `use sweph;` and this didn't generate any error. But then I tried `sweph::swe_set_ephe_path('/data/ephe');` and got 'Class sweph not found'. But it isn't a class...

Comment: Got it working! No need in `use`, I am simply using the functions as they are, like `swe_set_ephe_path('/data/ephe');`. All my previous problems were because Laravel didn't see the recently updated `php.ini` until I restarted the machine. Many thanks, @ThomasVanderVeen!